# Launch .NET Framework console app into a new window from inside a .NET Core Console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-4.7.1

I have a .NET Core console app (a TCP client) that needs to launch a .NET Framework console app (a TCP Server). I'm using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(server);` and it starts, but both console apps are in the same window. How can I get the server to run in a separate window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set the process properties as follows. You will get it in a new window.

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arg); 
p.UseShellExecute=true;
Process processChild = Process.Start(p); // separate window;
```